# I can not understand following: "$P = \rho_m RT$", is the document of Wikipedia wrong?

Tags: thermodynamics, ideal-gas

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equation_of_state_(cosmology)) says that,

$P=\rho_m RT$

P is pressure, $\rho_m$ is mass density, R is gas constant, T is temperature.

but I think it's wrong because of below equation.

$PV = nRT \\ \leftrightarrow PV = \frac{m}{M} RT \\ \leftrightarrow P =  \frac{1}{M} \frac{m}{V}RT \\ \leftrightarrow  P =  \frac{1}{M} \rho_mRT$

(M is molar mass)

If I am right, is the Wikipedia wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The equation of state can be written as:
$$PV = nR_u T$$
where $R_u=8.314\ J/mol\cdot K$ is the *universal gas constant*.

Indeed, we can rewrite the above equation as
$$PV = \frac{m}{M}R_u T$$
where $m$ is the total mass of the gas and $M$ is its molar mass. This becomes
$$P = \frac{m}{V} \frac{R_u}{M}T = \rho R T$$
where $\rho = m/V$ is the density and $R = R_u/M$ is the *specific gas constant*.

Answer (score 1):

The $R$ in your final equation is not the same $R$ in the Wikipedia equation. $R$ in $PV=nRT$ is the universal gas constant whereas $R$ in $PV=mRT$ is the specific gas constant. The number of moles $n$ equals the mass divided by the molecular weight. The universal gas constant equals the specific gas constant times the molecular weight.

Hope this